# Are iPhone App Requests On Topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm looking specifically at this proposal: [There's an app for that (iPhone apps)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22647/theres-an-app-for-that-iphone-apps)

> Proposed Q&A site for people who want to find and discuss iPhone apps. The app store is not a friendly place to search: this site would allow discussion of apps based on merit (user experience, feature set, ease of use) and allow finding by topic (eg shopping list apps).

Based on the description and the on-topic questions, would that content be welcomed on this site?

Please discuss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's just fine on Apple.SE as it will fit with all the other `[software-recommendation]` questions.

Comment: I do hope though that these questions do not overflow the site (as game-recommendations almost did on Gaming)

Answer (score 1):

As [Chealion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17/chealion) said it's fine and we also have a such question before:

- [can-you-recommend-a-numeracy-iphone-application-where-you-write-answers-on-the](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/can-you-recommend-a-numeracy-iphone-application-where-you-write-answers-on-the)
- [iphone-app-for-weather-push-notifications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/iphone-app-for-weather-push-notifications)
- [good-iphone-running-app-with-heart-rate-monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/good-iphone-running-app-with-heart-rate-monitor)
- ....